# This sql statement throws an error

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to get count data from the table using the following query

```
SELECT courses.published, courses.archived, courses.draft from
 (  select count(*) as published from courses where published = 't' union all
    select count(*) as draft from courses where draft = 't' union all
    select count(*) as archived from courses where archived = 't'
 ) as courses
```

I want a table where i can do this

```
$result['courses']['published']
$result['courses']['draft']
$result['courses']['archived']
```

but the query threw an error

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'courses.archived' in 'field list'
```

Comment: remove the `courses.` from in front of the published, archived, and draft in the top part.

Comment: @IanSellar still the same error

Comment: you are returning only one column (with three rows) from your inner query as you are combining them with UNION

Comment: @davek how can i achieve what i described?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
select p.published, d.draft, a.archived
from
( select count(*) as published from courses where published = 't' ) p
cross join
( select count(*) as draft from courses where draft = 't' ) d
cross join 
( select count(*) as archived from courses where archived = 't' ) a
```